# ion-select Multiple - How to unselect all other option based on selected option

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have something like the following:

```
                <ion-item color="dark">
                    <ion-select multiple value="any">
                        <ion-select-option value="any">Any</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="01">1</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="02">2</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="03">3</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="04">4</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="05">5</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="06">6</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="07">7</ion-select-option>
                        <ion-select-option value="08">8</ion-select-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
```

using Javascript I am wondering how to detect when a user selects a particular option eg if any is selected then then user also select 1 then Any should be deselected or if 1, 3, and 4 are select and then Any is selected the the others are deselected

Thanks

Comment: you can use `[disable]="OtherSelected"` attribute on any option.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib this is angular right? I am just using pure JS

Comment: still you have to do it in same way. use `ionChange ="youEventDetectFunction($event)"` and inside your function write your disabled logic.